# Android best practices for implementing a user guide

Tags: android, webview, user-guide

I want to implement a user guide in my app. But its not clear to me, what would be the best solution to do that. My idea for user guide based on a html faq, where user guide is a separate activity that has a table of contents at the top followed by the actual guide. The each item from table of contents is a link to a specific anchor in user guide. And the acitivty would have a back-to-top button.
My question is, how should i implement all those features? Should i work with typical View subclasses or should i try to implement a html document with a webview (I've never worked with web-related API's so i dont know if it possible to implement an offlane html document)

Edit: lesson learned. From now on i publish questions only about specific coding problems.

P.s. maybe anyone can suggest a site where you can discuss more general questions and suggestions?

Comment: Use a WebView to show an html file taken from your assets. You can add a button to scroll to top an another one to scroll to bottom, too.

Answer (score 2):

suggest you to create **menu_exit_help** contains:on **MainActivity(BaseActivity)**.Allow that one to appear on all the screen.

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_exit_help, menu);      
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }


    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuActionHelp) {
                Helper.walletGuidelines(this);
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

**menu_exit_help** contains:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuActionHelp"
        android:icon="?action_base_help"
        android:title="@string/action_help"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

**Helper.walletGuidelines(this)** is a seperate class . which helps to intearct with the **serverURL** for downloading the guide lines.